# Angular: get url query information

Tags: angular, routes

Assum I have the following url:

```
baseurl/customname/id/extend
```

for instance:

```
http://localhost:1111/person/23/extend
```

This route leads me to PersonComponent. In it I have to check the URL and if it fits -  open Modal window.
Currently I can just check "id" part like this

```
var id = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

But how can I check whether after this id there is also "extend" part?
Because I would need two different routes in future:

```
http://localhost:1111/person/23/extend (opens modal window for Extending)
http://localhost:1111/person/23/update (opens modal window for Updating)
```

Comment: if your route configured as `person/:id/:type`, you can access both props with `this.route.snapshot.params.id` and `this.route.snapshot.params.type`

Comment: The same way how you defined `:id` to be a param in your route, accessible via `snapshot.paramMap`, you now extend the route-definition by another dynamic key, say `:mode` (which is `'extend' | 'update'`).